# IF + AND Statements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, if-statement, scripting

I have a 'Current Result' in the form of a data frame in Python (depicting in Excel as an illustration).

I'd like to add a column that classifies whether a row is a 'PRIME' or an 'ALT' designation.

The rules for whether something is a 'ALT' is both of the following:

- 'Group' column is **not** 'NaN'
- AND
- 'Utilization' is always 0

[image]

Is a nested IF / AND statement the only concept that will work or is there a more efficient way to do this?  PS I am newer to Python.

ADDING EXAMPLE CODE OF A DATA FRAME:

```
import pandas as pd
 
### Generate data from lists.
data = {'Part':['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD','EEE','FFF','GGG', 'HHH', 'III', 'JJJ', 'LLL','MMM','NNN'], 'Group':['', '', '', '','','45','45', '45', '', 'FF', 'FF','7J','7J'], 'Utl':['0', '0', '0', '0','0','100','0', '0', '0', '100', '0','100','0']}
 
### Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
### Print the output.
print(df)
```

Comment: What does "***always** zero*" mean in your context?

Comment: It can be a string.  The 'Utilization' column in the screenshot will always show zero (along with the 'Group' column showing 'NaN') if the row is to be considered an 'ALT' value.

Comment: Then it's a single `IF` with two conditions joined by `AND`.

Comment: Would you be able to share?  I am still learning.

Comment: Would there also need to be a 'for' statement? @PM77-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kind of hard to re-create without digestible data, but I believe this will get you what you need IIUC

```
data = {
    'Group' : [np.nan, None, np.nan, '7f', '7f', '7f', None, None, None, '4j', '4j', None, None, '4j'],
    'Utilization':[0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 99]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#This is here just in case you have some np.nan's instead of None it'll make everything the same
df['Group'] = df['Group'].replace({np.nan : None})
condition_list = [
    (df['Group'].values == None) | ((df['Utilization']%2 == 0) & (df['Utilization'] > 0)), 
    (df['Group'].values != None) & (df['Utilization']%2 != 0) & (df['Utilization'] > 0),
    (df['Group'].values != None) & (df['Utilization'] == 0)
]
choice_list = ['Prime', 'Alt', 'Alt']
df['Check'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, 0)
df
```

Comment: I am actually seeing that this is setting everything to a 'Prime' value.

Comment: Ok, can you provide some programable data above then what it currently is and what you expect it to look like? This is probably what you need just needs a little tweak based on your dataset.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and submit over a data frame.  Thank you for your continued efforts!

Comment: No problem doesn’t have to be a ton probably only a couple rows would be enough to work with

Comment: I input '' values because I don't know how to insert a NaN.  Hope this isn't too inconvenient.  Thanks again! @ArchAngelPwn

Comment: @HelpMeCode Sorry it took me a while to get back, it was the end of the day at the last comment and then this morning I had a couple things to take care of. Let me know if the updated code works as you would expect. I was able to get the same results you had from your screenshot and added another random row of data to ensure that it looks like it was working correctly.